# How to work with FileReader 'synchronously' in react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filereader

I'm having a little trouble designing a solution to work with the FileReader API in a react/redux app due to it's asynchronous nature. I've done some looking around but nothing has worked for me.

I have a react component that makes use of react-dropzone to get contents of files and work on it's contents later on. Whenever a file get's dropped with dropzone, a callback fires:

```
onGuestListDrop = (fileData) => {
    const headers =
      FileParser.read(fileData)
        .getHeaders();
  };
```

The purpose of my internal API design is to get headers of .csv or .xlsx files in order to map the column names to existing system field names. I dont have any trouble parsing the content of the files, I got that working, the problem is with the FileReader.onload event.

My top leve file parser is:

```
class FileParser {

  constructor(file) {
    this.reader = new FileReader();
    this.init(file[0]);
    return this;
  }

  static read(file) {
    return new FileParser(file);
  }

  init(file) {
    switch (file.type) {
      case 'text/csv':
        this.parser = new CsvParser(this.reader, file);
        break;

      default:
        this.parser = new XlsParser(this.reader, file);
        break;
    }
  }

  getHeaders() {
    return this.parser.getHeaders();
  }
}
```

The CSV class is:

```
class CsvParser {

  constructor(reader, file) {
    this.reader = reader;
    this.file = file;
    this.parse();
    return this;
  }

  parse() {
    this.reader.readAsText(this.file, "UTF-8");
    this.reader.onload = function (evt) {
      const { result } = evt.target;
      this.parsedContent = Papa.parse(result);
      console.log(this.parsedContent);
    };
  }

  getHeaders() {
    return this.parsedContent.data[0];
  }
}
```

The problem right now is that when I try to access the headers via the getHeaders method I'm getting undefined because FileReader works async. Is there a way to make this work with some refactoring, or is this just not possible ?

I was thinking about using redux actions, but I'm not sure how to connect the parser classes with the store. I thought about passing an action directly to the parser class so I can fire the action creator within the FileReader.onload event. I think this could work, but I'm not sure this is the best approach to work with redux given the circumstances.

Comment: You need to use promises.

Answer (score 1):

Add a deferred pattern in your `CsvParser` like this.

```
class CsvParser {

 constructor(reader, file) {
  this.reader = reader;
  this.file = file;
  this.deferred = {};
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.deferred.resolve = resolve;
   this.deferred.reject = reject;
  });
  this.deferred.promise = promise;
  this.parse();
  return this;
 }

 parse() {
  this.reader.readAsText(this.file, "UTF-8");
   this.reader.onload = function (evt) {
   const { result } = evt.target;
   this.parsedContent = Papa.parse(result);
   console.log(this.parsedContent);
   this.deferred.resolve(this.parsedContent.data[0])
  };
}

getHeaders() {
 return this.deferred.promise;
}
```

Now change your `onGuestListDrop` method like this

```
onGuestListDrop = (fileData) => {
  let headers = {};
  FileParser.read(fileData).getHeaders().then(function (headers) {
    headers = headers;
  });
};
```